# Can a two-sided lightsaber have two different colored blades?

Tags: star-wars

I have always seen two-sided lightsabers with both blades having same color. Can those blades have different colors?

Have we seen them in the canon? Or, is it not possible theoretically because there can only be one crystal inside a lightsaber or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't remember any canon appearance of such a combination, but at least based on Episode 1 - as far as I remember it - it's not impossible.

Darth Maul's "twin blade" has two blades that can be activated individually. Although unlikely, during one of the fights the blade is cut right in the middle, leaving two separate and still operating halves, which would suggest there are two independent emitters/weapons inside, so it would be totally possible to use different crystals for both.

[image: Darth Maul]

Comment: `it would be totally possible to use different crystals for both` ~> What if Kyber Crystals repel each other or annihilate?

Comment: @11.01.11 Grievous would have an issue. 